# PHP Image Resize with the given scale

Tags: php, image, resize, image-resizing

I have a JQuery plugin for image cropping in the browser. its working the problem is i don't understand this "scale" part.

Original Image Size: 640x640

Jquery guillotine plugin result data:

```
{ scale: 0.9, angle: 0, x: 10, y: 20, w: 400, h: 400 }
```

I'm confused about the scale.

[edit]:

this is my PHP code:

```
$filename = $this->data['img_file'];
$scale = round($this->data['scale'],2);
$angle = 360 - $this->data['angle'];
$x = $this->data['x'];
$y = $this->data['y'];
$w = $this->data['w'];
$h = $this->data['h'];

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $scale;
$new_height = $height * $scale;

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

$image_s = imagecreatetruecolor(400,400);
imagecopyresampled($image_s, $image_p, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h, 400, 400);
```

[FIXED]

Comment: What's the plugin? This question cannot be answered without code.

Comment: What are you confused about? You haven't asked a question.. Also, how is this related to PHP?

Comment: Like the guys above say, this isn't really a question. It's a statement. What do you actually want to know. Provide some code examples and remove the php tag as this has nothing to do with php.

Comment: yes it is related to PHP... because im implementing the server side of this script i dont know how to "resize" the image using the "scale" given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling will resize an image based on percentage usually.  So if you leave it at 1 it should stay at 100%, but cropping an image will actually remove pixels from the image while changing the scale will either shrink or enlarge the image pixel spacing.

Comment: Actually my plugin works that way.. its like facebook photo cropping but with zoom in and zoom out.. so i get it the scale i should change it to percent... thanks..